# Complex sorting in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have written a script that fulfills the extraction requirement but I cannot sort the results according to the formatting requirements. This is my script:

```
awk '{print $9"  "$1}' ab.log | sort | uniq -c | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3}' | sort -nr
```

It shows the status code and IP address in descending order;

```
404   89.86.144.219
404   81.192.148.245
.
.
403   172.6.0.3
403   129.16.26.39
402   145.8.0.9
402   256.23.4.57
.
.
401   126.158.20.9
```

But the requirements are:
status code groups have to be sorted by which status code group appears more often and the IP addresses have to be sorted by occurrence within each of the groups.

So the output should be:

```
404    127.0.0.1
404    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
.
.
200    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
200    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
.
.
403    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
403    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

How can I sort the result according to the above requirements?

Comment: Please, post some sample data for testing to go with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably an amazing single command you can use for this. However here is a pipeline using awk, sort and cut:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]++;b[$0]=$1}END{for(i in b) printf "%-9d%s\n",a[b[i]],i}' | sort -k1,1nr -k2,2n -k3,3 | cut -c9-
```

With GNU awk, you could even make it into a single command, but it just will start to look messy

Comment: thanks for reply me
i tried first but it's not working

Comment: can we do this without "awk" ?

Comment: @zeetest8428 You don't like awk?

Comment: the requirement is to do this without "awk" . we can use "awk" only for formatting