# How to show specific number of rows from a log file in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I want to display a specific number of rows from all groups.
I used `head -n 3` but this shows only 3 rows from all the rows

```
cat $4 | awk '{print $9"  "$1}' | sort | uniq -c  | awk '{print $2 "\t" $3}' | sort -nr | head -n 3 
404  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
404  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
404  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

but the requirement is to show 3 rows from every group of status code
output should be

```
404  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
404  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
404  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

200  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
200  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
200  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

403  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
403  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
403  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

401  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
401  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
401  xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

how can i do this

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66237179/complex-sorting-in-shell-script

Comment: @JamesBrown its not related to that one, this question about show specific number of result and the question in the link is how to sort the result

Comment: It's related in a such way that when you post some testable sample data to the linked question, you'll probably receive a whole package that solves both these questions.

Comment: By the by, http://shellcheck.net/ points out some obvious problems with your script. You want to fix those before asking, as they are distracting and possibly misleading.

Answer (score 3):

To get, for example, 2 lines of each `$1`, you can use:

```
$ awk '++a[$1]<=2' file
```